# Custom Cursor on Microsoft Edge has an Offset

Tags: css, cursor, microsoft-edge

I have a custom cursor working on Chrome and Firefox by using the CSS property, cursor. However, on Microsoft Edge, the cursor seems to have an offset. I have to aim above my custom cursor a bit in order to select items accurately.

Is there something I can do to fix this? Or is this some sort of limitation?

Edit: I should mention that I'm using a custom image as my cursor.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In both IE and Edge only .cur files are supported, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358795(v=vs.85).aspx. (Edge supports other formats but not the interaction point definition as you mentioned in your comment to Martin Beeby's answer, rendering those pretty useless.) The .cur file allows you to define the interaction point. Just google for ".cur editor" and choose the editor that suits you to create a .cur file.

Since other browsers do support the definition for the interaction point, but not the .cur format, you must define two cursor properties in your css, the first with the .cur file and the second with a .png or other format and the interaction point definition. IE and Edge will ignore the second and for other browsers the .cur file will be overwritten, that way it'll work cross-browser.

```
div {
    cursor: url(path/to/cursor.cur), auto; /*IE and Edge*/
    cursor: url(path/to/cursor.png) 4 12, auto; /*Chrome, FF, etc.*/ 
}
```

One side note, be sure to read this (http://blog.stchur.com/2006/11/02/ie-bug-dealing-with-css-custom-cusors/) article. It's about a relative path bug in IE 6 & 7, but the bug is still around in IE 11. The bug seems resolved in Edge though (at least when I tried recently). So you need to fiddle a bit with the path to the .cur file to get it working on both IE and Edge. See the workarounds mentioned in the article.

Comment: Edge did not support my gif cursor. I had to do "cursor: url(cursor.gif), url(cursor.cur), auto;" to make the cursor work in Edge in Windows 10. The cursor was easily created from my gif with a free tool called RealWorld Cursor Editor. I first tried an online site to convert it but it screwed up the transparency of the cursor, so I installed that freeware software instead and it did the job perfectly.

Comment: Hi @Sandhje Bouw, can you help take a look at my custom cursor issue in Edge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791794/edge-customize-cursor-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can pass in coordinates which specify the interaction point.

Perhaps adding these will help solve your issue?

```
/* Using URL and coordinates */
cursor:  url(cursor1.png) 4 12, auto;
```

Comment: Hey, I did try this (probably should have mentioned above), but once I add the coordinates the custom cursor just disappears in Edge. Checking the "Inspect Element/Dev" console shows that Edge ignores the cursor command when they are added.