# Customizing cursor doesn't work on Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I am trying to modify the mouse cursor ; it works well for Chrome / Firefox / Safari, but not for Edge.
Here the part of the css which defines the path to the custom cursor image :

```
&.eraser {
    cursor: url('../assets/img/eraser.png'), auto;
}
```

I checked the post [Edge customize cursor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791794/edge-customize-cursor-doesnt-work) but it didn't solve my problem, since the path is already defined according to the css file.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the path to the image valid? Does the element have the "&" and "eraser" classes?

Comment: Yes. The code is the same for all the browsers I quoted...

Comment: It looks like the above code is SCSS is it in a css or scss file?

Comment: Just to be clear, You have an index file somewhere. You also have a css file somewhere. The **parent of the folder that contains the css file** also contains a folder called `assets`. In it lives a folder `img` and inside _that_ is your image. Correct?

Comment: it is correct. :) and yes I am using scss; I didn't mention it because I didn't know that it could make a difference .

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that IE handles relative paths different than other browsers. To test if this is the problem, try hardcoding an absolute path to that image.

If THAT works, then you can have SASS compile that relative path into the environment-appropriate absolute path by setting `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://your.domain.com/"` in your grunt task.